# PL/SQL: how to combine rows into one string

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using PL/SQL on Oracle Database 12c.

I have a table like this:

```
filename | priority                         
---------- -----------
foo  |    1         
bar  |    2   
baz  |    3
```

I want to create this string: foo, 1, bar, 2, baz, 3

What's the best way to do this? Previously I used SQL Server and this worked:

```
DECLARE 
   @str varchar(100)
SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + ', ', '') + CONCAT(filename, ', ', priority) 
FROM table_name;
```

But I'm trying to do this in Oracle now and I can't get it to work. I've tried a few methods like:

```
DECLARE 
   str varchar(100) := coalesce(str || ', ', '') || CONCAT(filename, ', ', priority) 
FROM table_name;
```

But I was given this error, "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following"

I also tried listagg like:

```
listagg(filename|| ',' || priority, ',') within group (order by priority) as str 
from table_name;
```

This gave me the error, "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WITHIN" when expecting one of the following"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DECLARE...FROM TABLE_NAME`???

Comment: Why do you need a procedure (and PL/SQL) code at all? You can do this in plain SQL. Then - WHY do you need to do this? There may be (much) better ways to do what you need; we may be able to help, if you would explain WHY you need it.

Comment: I am modifying existing code that was written with PL/SQL to include a new feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stored procedure in Oracle consists of a declaration part and an execution part. You use the `DECLARE` section for declaring variables and the block from `BEGIN` to `END` for the program. Use `SELECT INTO` to select a value into your variable.

```
DECLARE 
  v_str varchar(10000);
BEGIN
  select 
    listagg(filename || ',' || priority, ',') within group (order by priority)
  into v_str
  from table_name;

  ...
END;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize the declaration could not go in the same block as the execution code.